# I have an issue printing out an array

Tags: c++

I cant figure out why this wont print out correctly.

```
void countChars(ifstream& inData, string filename, int x[], int y[])
{
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < 58; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
}
    inData.open(filename.c_str());

    while (inData >> ch)
    {
        count++;
        if ((ch >= '!') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            x[ch - '!']++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 58; i++)
    {
        y[i] = (x[i] / count * 100);
        cout << y[i] << endl;
    }   
}
```

It should print out the % of the file each character makes up.  What it does print out is 58 0s.  I don't understand exactly why it doesn't print out right, I reread the chapters on arrays and couldn't find anything about this type of problem.  I tried to search first but I'm not even sure what terms I should be searching for with this problem.

Comment: `x[i] / count` is an integer operation that results in 0 since an integer is a whole number, not a floating point one.  Rearrange your formula so this doesn't happen, or cast one of the integers to a float.

Comment: @RetiredNinja  Agree. Expect 0 or 100 and nothing in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays x,y and count are integer arrays. So as x[i] < count always, the division value is always 0. so change x, y, count as double..

Comment: Except when every character is the same and within range.

Comment: @bvj: ya, but with a really less probability

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously in your line

```
y[i] = x[i] / count * 100
```

every field in your x-Array is probably smaller than count thus the result of your division is always below 1, since you chose to use integers that's always 0 and 0 * 100 = still 0.

Answer (score 1):

change data types of either of the x or count to float or double.

Answer (score 1):

```
y[i] = (int)(x[i] * 100.0 / count + 0.5);
```